# building battery pack for HP Dv6 2064ca

Tags: laptop, battery

I replaced my battery pack with anker brand. It went faulty and was not charging. So they sent another pack which was turned out to be faulty. Now i got 2 battery packs sitting of now use. If i want to replace the cells what consideration should i take.

** How to calculate current. Original and replacement battery are 10.8 V. Which cells should i use (3.7 or less). Dont want to burn the laptop with more voltage.

I will greatly appreciate if any one can help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about rebuilding a battery (that just happens to be from a notebook).  Probably better on http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Use 10.8/BatteryVoltage number of batteries in series, example:
Lithium batteries are 3.7 or 4.2, 
so 10.8/3.7 ~= 3 
so three batteries in series will provide roughly 10.8(11.1 which could be an issue)
then to increase current(If I remember correctly) you would use sets of three wired in parallel.(so 3 batteries wired in series, then wired in parallel with another set of 3 wired in series)
I do not usually work with electronics, so I reccomend checking all this information is correct, since 11.1v might not work with your laptop.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If i want to built a high capacity battery.(reasonable price) Anker claimed 8800mah but i saw 5000mah on ebay. Are 8800mah available online ?

Comment: @max Pretty much any battery is availible online, since you're building a custom battery I reccomend trying to go for more than 8800.

Comment: I searched ebay and other local store. Ebay max i can find is 5300mah. Store dont have them. May be you can help in pointing at right source.

Comment: @max Just search laptop battery, http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-PA3817U-1BRS-Genuine-Original-Toshiba-Satellite-L655-L655D-Battery-PC-Laptop-/261205105869?pt=Laptop_Batteries